# Files Missing after upgrade Magento 2.4.1 to 2.4.6-p3

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade Magento `2.4.1 to 2.4.6`

```
PHP version  7.4
Composer version 2.6.5
```

Below steps I have followed to upgrade

1- `cp composer.json composer.json.bak`

2- `composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin=~2.0 --no-update`

3- `composer require  magento/product-community-edition=2.4.5 --no-update`

4- copied contents of "`require-dev`"  from `https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.6-p3/composer.json`
and placed in my root `composer.json` file

5- `Changed PHP version to 8.2`

6- `composer update` While running this command there were below prompts which I set `y`

7- Do you trust "`magento/composer-root-update-plugin`" to execute code and wish to enable it now? (writes "allow-plugins" to composer.json) [y,n,d,?] y

8- Do you trust "`magento/composer-dependency-version-audit-plugin`" to execute code and wish to enable it now? (writes "allow-plugins" to composer.json) [y,n,d,?] y

9- Do you trust "`magento/inventory-composer-installer`" to execute code and wish to enable it now? (writes "allow-plugins" to composer.json) [y,n,d,?] y

These all steps went smoothly without any errors.

But the weird thing is many files are missing like Magento and .htaccess files in the `bin folder`

also in app/etc and bootstrap.php also missing

HOwever before doing all above steps site is running properly and all files ere available.

How to fix these?

Comment: Please check the system requirements : https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html

Comment: Your Composer version is higher than the requirement.

Comment: did you get the error like ``There is an error in /app/vendor/magento/module-admin-adobe-ims/Model/GetAccessTokenProxy.php at line: 17
Interface "Magento\AdobeImsApi\Api\GetAccessTokenInterface" not found#0 /app/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571): include()
#1 /app/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/app/vendor/com...')
#2 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Magento\\AdminAd...')
``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Please remove your old vendor folder**

```
rm -rf vendor/
```

**Then, add the proper Composer version as per the document, which is 2.2.x. I used 2.2.18, which works well in our system. After that, please run the Composer commands.**

**System Requirements :** https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html

```
composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6-p3  --no-update --verbose
composer update
```

**Reference Link:** https://github.com/magento/composer-root-update-plugin/tree/develop/src/Magento/ComposerRootUpdatePlugin#usage

Comment: The main issue was composer version 2.4.6. I thought Magento 2.4.6 support minimum composer version 2.2.x and any latest version but this was not the case so i degraded to 2.2.x and issue solved.